# Should I include the proposed method name in manuscript Keywords section?

Tags: publications, journals, keywords

The JASA manuscript template contains the `Keywords` section to insert 3-6 keywords. Is it appropriate to insert there the proposed method name as one of the Keywords?

If yes, should I use method's acronym (well-sounded but not self-explanatory, a 5 letters-long word) or the full name (4 words)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is important to your work (e.g. if the method has a "blind spot" so the results might have a loophole) then yes, include it as a keyword.

As for whether to use the full name or the acronym, either is fine. When the template says "3-6 keywords", chances are very good that each group of words is one keyword. For example, "United States" would be one keyword, even though it's two English words.